# Advice picking colors for a videogame interface

Tags: color, interface-design, games, palette

I've been working on developing a card-based browser game, and I have to say graphic design isn't my *forte*.

This is what the user interface for the game looks like

[image]

I'm not too sure about the choice of colors for the various buttons and elements of the UI.
Specifically, while I like the green portions and wooden background (although I'm open to suggestions on those as well), I would like some tips on how I could pick better suited colors for my interface.

Those greys are just... meh, in my opinion.

[Here's](https://samul-1.github.io/test1/127.0.0.1.html) a mockup page that you can play with modifying CSS (although the background is missing, sorry about that).

What colors could I use in place of those that better suit the other elements of the UI?
Thank you.

Comment: Uhm, okay...     And?

Answer (score 1):

It looks pretty good to me- only thing, maybe darken all the wooden boards to match the ones around the red stack of face-down cards (or under the "dubito" button). That way there is more contrast with the emoji faces- the wood is just a bit too busy with the dark and light shades and is distracting (and I don't think that much shade variation is needed for a background element).

Answer (score 1):

You are doing good work. The green and wood look nice.

The buttons could be simply transparent and black. Probably you could use a transparent white in some places.

One thin border could work in some preponderant sections.

[image]

One thing I should recommend is that you use open source emoji, do not use some proprietary ones so you do not have any problems. Here is one example: https://openmoji.org/library/#search=face